# Mac application About menu customisation

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am doing my first mac application. I have added my menus and customized. What is my problem is that I need some customizations in the about view. While the about menu clicked, automatically a view will pops up with details Name, Icon, copyright string, version etc. fetched from application plist. About menu in XCode application, which has buttons for Acknowledgment and Licensee Agreement. In chrome About Chrome will create a new tab in the webpage and details are shown. How this possible? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can do it in your `MainMenu.xib`, change to the target-action of the menu item `About myApp` to your custom action.

See the doc:

> ## Connecting Menu Items Across Nib Files
>
> The items in an OS X application’s menu bar often need to interact
> with many different objects, including your application’s documents
> and windows. The problem is that many of these objects cannot (or
> should not) be accessed directly from the main nib file. The File’s
> Owner of the main nib file is always set to an instance of the
> NSApplication class. And although you might be able to instantiate a
> number of custom objects in your main nib file, doing so is hardly
> practical or necessary. In the case of document objects, connecting
> directly to a specific document object is not even possible because
> the number of document objects can change dynamically and can even be
> zero.
>
> Most menu items send action messages to one of the following:
>
> - A fixed object that always handles the command
> - A dynamic object, such as a document or window
>
> Messaging fixed objects is a relatively straightforward process that
> is usually best handled through the application delegate. The
> application delegate object assists the NSApplication object in
> running the application and is one of the few objects that rightfully
> belongs in the main nib file. If the menu item refers to an
> application-level command, you can implement that command directly in
> the application delegate or just have the delegate forward the message
> to the appropriate object elsewhere in your application.
>
> If you have a menu item that acts on the contents of the frontmost
> window, you need to link the menu item to the First Responder
> placeholder object. If the action method associated with the menu item
> is specific to one of your objects (and not defined by Cocoa), you
> must add that action to the First Responder before creating the
> connection.
>
> After creating the connection, you need to implement the action method
> in your custom class. That object should also implement the
> validateMenuItem: method to enable the menu item at appropriate times.
> For more information about how the responder chain handles commands,
> see Cocoa Event Handling Guide.